# Ordering a JSON dumps by a value in one of the lists of the class in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm having a bit of trouble with ordering my JSON output. Below is the class Rolodex, which contains the two lists entries and errors. Now the output is properly formatted, as shown below, but I'm having issues with how it's being ordered.

```
class Rolodex:
  def __init__(self):
    self.entries = []
    self.errors = []

class Entry:
  def __init__(self):
    color = None
    firstname = None
    lastname = None
    phonenumber = None
    zipcode = None

def encode_rolo(obj):
  if isinstance(obj, Entry):
    return obj.__dict__
  else:
    raise TypeError("Unserializable object {} of type {}".format(obj,type(obj)))

output.write(json.dumps(rolo.__dict__, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '), default=encode_rolo).encode('utf-8'))
```

Here's the output (truncated):

```
{
    "entries": [
        {
            "color": "aqua marine",
            "firstname": "Ria",
            "lastname": "Tillotson",
            "phonenumber": "196-910-5548",
            "zipcode": "97671"
        },
        {
            "color": "blue",
            "firstname": "Annalee",
            "lastname": "Loftis",
            "phonenumber": "905-329-2054",
            "zipcode": "97296"
        },
        ...

    ],
    "errors": [
        1,
        6,
        ...
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the keys in the entries list are ordered just fine. But I want to be able to order the entries themselves by (Lastname, Firstname). Is there some way to do that with json.dumps?

Comment: Did you try to sort entries before `json.dumps`?

Comment: That works. Silly me. The added code:
`rolo.entries = sorted(rolo.entries, key=attrgetter('lastname', 'firstname'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it via sorting before converting into json.

For example:

```
entries.sort(key=lambda e: e['lastname']+e['firstname'])
```

Comment: Alternatively: `rolo.entries = sorted(rolo.entries, key=attrgetter('lastname', 'firstname'))`

Thank you for your help. For some reason it didn't click that I could ensure that the list was sorted before dumping to json.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, your issue here is merely that `Rolodex.entries` is in insertion order, not sorted by the names as you want them to. You could make that attribute a property instead of the regular attribute which it currently is, and have the setter sort the attribute on every insertion. Here's how:

```
class Rolodex(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.errors = []
        self._entries = []

    @property
    def entries(self):
        self._entries.sort(key=lambda x: (x.lastname, x.firstname))
        return self._entries
```

The way this works is that your entries list is actually stored in `Rolodex._entries`, a private attribute of the Rolodex instance. Now, to make `Rolodex.entries` work as you want it to, we make it a [property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property). What this essentially means is that you define a method that should be ran every time something tries to access the entries, including of course `json.dumps()`. In this specific case, we sort the private entries list of your class based on your criteria, and then just return that, every time anything accesses it.

Note that you have to inherit from `object` with your classes for this functionality to work (this is how you use [new-style classes](https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/), and you should make a habit of always inheriting from `object`, anyway.)

Also note that this implementation is rather inefficient, but is the most readable and easiest to understand that I could come up with. You most likely don't need better performance, either—but if I'm wrong on this one, you should look into the [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module and use that for efficient insertion in your list, with a setter method you can read about in the property documentation I linked above.